# git log across moves

Tags: git, revision-history

I have a file in Git called `templating/motorcalc.py` and the whole `templating` directory was renamed `templates`

How can I see the whole log for `motorcalc.py`? It stops at the rename point and I can't figure out how to see earlier history.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, I just found the [`--follow` option.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Comment: why is it that when I search for stuff before turning to SO, I can't find anything, but *after* I post, my luck at searching for answers improves?